# nginx with hhvm - Not found

Tags: php, nginx

I'v set up nginx with hhvm but, 
any file .php returns me "**Not found**" except 
index.php that returns me **Running on HHVM version 2.3.2**.

Some of my configurations

**/etc/nginx/sites-enable/default**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

**/etc/hhvm/server.hdf**

```
Server {
  Port = 80
  SourceRoot = /usr/share/nginx/www/
  DefaultDocument = index.php
}
```

Comment: Paul Tarjan, from http://www.hhvm.com, asked if files are in “**/usr/share/nginx/www/**” and the **www-data** user has access to read them. And yes.

Comment: Were you able to get a resolution for this? I am running into the same problem.